# Open Web Browser from App - Always Crashes

Tags: android

I'm trying to open a web browser from my app using:

```
 Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://developer.android.com/"));
             startActivity(browser);
```

But the app just crashes:

```
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3131)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3237)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at com.Co.DrumKit$9.onClick(DrumKit.java:658)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-07 17:18:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show the entire `com.Co.DrumKit` class, as something appears to be very broken in this activity.

Comment: The issue isn't with those lines, something else is causing the issue.